# Python XML Parser Loading Numbers as strings

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file with about 15000 values in it.  I read it using

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

An example of how I pulled out a value is

`def get_year1_quantity(element):
    return element[5][0].text`
I got all the data and put the different values into list, then put them into a pandas dataframe.

I tried to filter the data by:

`filtered=this[this.Year1_Q > this.Year2_Q]`

Everything went well in till I looked at the data in a csv file.  Only a few of the values are loaded as strings.  They go into excel as floats or int depending on the values.  I tried

`Year1_Q=[map(int, x) for x in Year1_Q]
        Year1_P=[map(float, x) for x in Year1_P]
        Year2_Q=[map(int, x) for x in Year2_Q]
        Year2_P=[map(float, x) for x in Year2_P]`

but it gave me an error, Year1_Q=[map(int, x) for x in Year1_Q]

ValueError: could not convert string to int:

It does not make sense to me that some numbers are loaded as numbers, while others are loaded as strings.  They are identical in the xml file.

Has anyone had this problem before?

I tried `this[columns]=this[columns].astype(float)` and got invalid literal for float(): 6,625.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a text file and only you know whether it should be interpreted as string or as a number. When you need it as a number in Python, you have to explicitly convert it (as you do with map). The CSV is also a text format.

You can use

```
try:
    Year1_Q=[map(int, x) for x in Year1_Q]
except ValueError:
    print(repr(Year1_Q))
```

to make the problematic value visible.

The CSV is not a native Excel format. Excel may be the tool to be blamed. The result may differ when you double click on the CSV file or when you start Excel and open the CSV file via menu (this is real observation at least for some older versions of Excel).

Comment: Thank You for the reply.  It showed that once it got str for one group of values, it turned them all the values into a str.  I just wrote out a csv file, loaded it back in, and worked from there.

Comment: @lost: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) pepr's answer if it's helped.  Thanks.